# shop sitemap with each product on its own subdomains

Tags: seo, subdomain, sitemap, multi-subdomains

My client has a shop and he want's me to create sitemap with products.
The problem is that each product has its own subdomain. Every products uses the same layout as homepage and non-subdomain pages.
I cannot change subdomain products to be on directory like: `/product/raspberry-diet-supplement`
On non-subdomain pages there is some texts. There a blog, contact page, categories.

If I submit the sitemap to Google Console without links to products on subdomains will it hurt my clients SEO or will it help SEO?
How would you handle situations like this?

Comment: Sitemaps have almost nothing to do with SEO.   Neither adding your site to Google Search Console, nor submitting your sitemap will improve rankings.   At best sitemaps give you additional data in Google Search Console and can be used by Google to figure out your preferred URLs when Google finds duplicates.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this type of store is not recommended with products in subdomains.
By the way, every subdomain should have separate property in Google Search Console. So, you couldn't import sitemaps for subdomains in root domain property. It's better to add separate property for each subdomains.
In this case, from the perspective of SEO, its better to work on product's blog page in directories and drive incoming users to product's subdomain by the purchase link in product's blog page.